# Why can I pass a variable to a function that should take a pointer?

Tags: c++

I have a function that should take a pointer to some data (In this case an array)

```
unsigned int someclass::foo(const void* data)
```

But calling it with the code below compiles and functions without issues

```
float someData[] = {1.0f, 2.0f};
unsigned int Result = someclass.foo(someData);
```

Not only that however, but passing it by reference, as I understand it should work, also functions perfectly, even though in one case, I am passing a variable, and in the other, I am passing a reference to one.

```
float someData[] = {1.0f, 2.0f};
unsigned int Result = someclass.foo(&someData);
```

Why are these two behaving the same? Am I missing something critical in my understanding of pointers?

Comment: C-array decays into a pointer.

Comment: `someclass.foo(&someData)` is not passing by reference. Instead you're passing the address of `someData`